# How can I figure out the name of a JSP tag in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

Currently I have the following code:

```
Tag tag = getParent();

while(tag != null) {
    parents.append("child of ")
           .append(tag.getClass().getName())
           .append("\n");
    tag = tag.getParent();
}
```

when this runs, I get the following:

```
com.mystuff.mvc.tag.MyTag 
child of org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
child of javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAdapter
child of javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAdapter
child of javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAdapter
child of javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAdapter
child of javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAdapter
```

`MyTag` is a Java class and so I can get the name from `getName()`. Unfortunately neither `Tag` nor `TagAdapter` give me methods to find out the name of the actual tag. `Class.getName()` only returns `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagAdapter` if the tags are `.tag` files. I understand that the `.tag` files eventually get converted to `.java` files and then compiled into `.class` files. So if I have a tag called `awesome.tag` then the corresponding file is `awesome_tag.java`. I don't understand why this name doesn't show up when I call `getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
String name = tag.getClass().getName();
if (tag instanceof TagAdapter) {
  name = ((TagAdapter)tag).getAdaptee().getClass().getName();
}
parents.append("child of ").append(name).append("\n");
```